# Best way to find a non-stubbed transition wrapper with vue-test-utils v1

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, transition, vue-test-utils

I am upgrading a very large application from vue-test-utils beta to v1. Previously when testing transitions vue-test-utils had TransitionStub and TransitionGroupStub components pre-stubbed and available to find and interact with transitions. I know I can create my own...

```
const TransitionStub = {
    render() {
        return this.$options._renderChildren;
    },
};
```

which works for simple situations, but if I shallowMount a component with a transition and want to emit an `after-enter` event to test what occurs after, what would make the most sense? This component currently renders the transition like so when not stubbed:

`<div name="opacity" enter-class="opacity-enter" enter-active-class="opacity-enter-active" leave-active-class="opacity-leave-active" leave-to-class="opacity-leave-to" mode="out-in">`

and I can do `wrapper.findAll('div')` and emit the `after-enter` event where I would previously do `wrapper.findAll(TransitionStub)`, but finding a transition by it's tag is very much so not a trustworthy strategy.

If I stub the transition with the above code, I'm getting a `[Vue warn]: Multiple root nodes returned from render function. Render function should return a single root node.` in my test. Another complication here is that the transitions are inside table columns, though I am only passing data for one column in this test.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered a solution. In v1 when transitions are not automatically stubbed, you can find by the `transition-stub` element. In beta you can pass false to not stub the transition: `stubs: { transition: false }` and then find by `transition-stub`.